# what does "私なりに..." mean?

Tags: translation

In a daily conversation, I heard this sentence:

> **私なりに** 添削してみましたが他の方の意見も参考にしてみてください！

I think I understand, but I have never heard "noun + なりに + ..." before.

1. What does "私なりに..." mean?
2. How can it be generalized to other nouns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

～なりに means "in one's own way/style".  So that sentence means

> I corrected it in my own way, but please get others' opinions too!

1. So 私なりに～ means "in my own way", and is a very common phrase to see for ～なりに.
2. It can basically be generalized to any other noun.  It is used when that "style" can be emphasized for the situation.

> - 私は私なりに[価値観]{か・ち・かん}を持っている　→　I have my own set of values.
> - 子供は子供なりに率直に話す　→　Children speak very frankly in their own way.
> - 彼は彼なりに問題の[解決策]{かい・けつ・さく}を求めている　→　He is looking for a solution to the problem in his own manner.

There is also the form `Noun1 + なりの + Noun2`.  It shifts the focus of the "style" from the verb action to Noun2.

> - 教授なりの考え　→　Professors' own idea
> - [田舎]{≪いなか≫}はそれなりの魅力がある　→　The country(side) has a charm of its own

In my opinion the nuances are subtle enough that なりに and なりの seem pretty interchangeable when a Noun2 is involved (someone correct me on this if I'm wrong).  For example, compare

> - 私は**私なりに**[価値観]{か・ち・かん}を**持っている**　→　I have my own set of values (the "having" is done in my own way).
> - 私は**私なりの[価値観]{か・ち・かん}**を持っている　→　I have my own set of values (the values are my own, but I have them the same way everyone else does).

Answer (score 1):

Xなりに means in X's own way. It restricts the scope of the succeeding statement so that it does not hold in general. I.e. it is valid in X's interpretation but not *necessarily* valid in other interpretations.

The に is just the particle に. Using の would create a noun phrase:

XなりのY would mean X's own Y, for example 私なりの考え would be "my own thoughts/idea"