# Meaning of それなりに

Tags: grammar, meaning

> ダドリーがドタドタと、それなりに全速力でやってきた。
> Dudley came waddling towards them as fast as he could (original text).

Most references suggest that それなりに means 'in its own way'.

This might be a grey area, but does それなりに全速力で really mean "as fast as he could"? Literally I think it means "with a maximum speed which is unique to him" which you might argue means "as fast as possible" but I don't really think so.

What nuance does それなりに actually give in this sentence? Would there be a difference if I substituted それなりに with なるべく or できるだけ?

Comment: Do native speakers of English feel he was not that fast because of the word "waddle"? If you do, the translator might have tried to express that with それなり.

Comment: @aguijonazo Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think interpreting それなり as *in its own way* or *given the constraints* as jogloran's answer should be fine.

In general, それなり means *moderately* and kind of diminishes what it modifies. E.g.

- それなりに分かった I understood to an extent (but not completely)
- それなりに面白い moderately/mildly interesting/amusing (it's ok, but not super)

So, それなりに in the sentence puts a reservation on 全速力で, as in *as fast as possible, but to the moderate extent*. If this is odd in English, in Japanese somehow it works. I suppose 全速力で is understood practically as *very fast*, and それなりに全速力で as *very fast as is possible by Dudley*. In this sense, それなりに relativizes the maximum (speed).

---

できるだけ would be odd here. It would sound redundant to 全速力で, which already contains the "as much as" sense. できるだけ速く is ok (although I feel できるだけはやく more often means できるだけ早く=as early as possible).

なるべく won't fit here either. It typically comes with a request or ようにした as seen in [these examples](https://j-nihongo.com/narubeku/).

Answer (score 2):

I think the relevant sense is “as fast as possible given the constraints” — clearly referring to Dudley’s legendary size.

Answer (score 2):

(X)なり is a suffix that forms a no-adjective meaning something like "no more or less than what X can do", "as much as can be expected on X", "(at least) to the extent of X's worth", etc. See: [what does "私なりに..." mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23601/5010)

Note that -なり sometimes appears to mean "moderately", but that's not the original meaning of the word. For example, 値段なりの味 ("taste worth the price") refers to a mediocre taste when the price is neither high nor low, but it refers to a good taste when the price is high, or a bad taste when the price is very low. 努力なりの結果 ("the result corresponding to the amount of your effort") can be a great, so-so, or poor result, depending on the amount of the effort. それなりの男と結婚した means that someone married an excellent, decent, mediocre, or below-average man, depending on what kind of person the bride is.

それなり in your sentence is the same as 彼なり. それなりの全速力 (or 彼なりの全速力) is not a typical full speed that you usually imagine, but a kind of "full speed" that you can expect from him. In this case, readers know Dudley is not good at running, so it works as a little sarcastic expression that indicates that his "full speed" was not really very fast, but at least he did his best.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Regarding "but it refers to a **good** taste when the price is **high**, or a **bad** taste when the price is very **low**", I'm a little confused. If I said "it's good for/considering the price" in English  I would be saying that, "even though it is cheap it is better than I expected". I wonder if you meant to say "it refers to a **good** taste when the price is **low**" or whether I've failed to understand your explanation.

Comment: @user3856370 値段なりだ does not carry a sense of surprise like "good for the price". It's "as good as it should be for the price", "neither bad nor good for the price". When you say 高かったけど値段なりに美味しい, it means "It was expensive but it tastes good enough (accordingly)".