# What does それなりに means in this conttext?

Tags: meaning, particle-に, sentence

[image]

So the character in the top panel asks how much  a custom made order suits costs. After he gets told the price he points out is very expensive (高い) to which the other character replies それなりに

My understanding of the world is that reduces/put a limit on the previous one, however I struggle to understand how it's used with 高い? Is he saying is not that actually that expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, それなりに(高い) indicates that, although it's expensive, it's priced to *reflect the value of the suit and the effort to make it*. This それ vaguely refers to the value/quality/effort associated with the custom-made suit, and Xなりに indicates "as much as can be expected based on X". For details, see [my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/98577/5010). In other words, while admitting it's expensive, he is satisfied with it because of the high quality.

Note that それなりの値段 may refer to a low price when they're talking about cheap suits.